# Take Value of Each Elemenet of STR Until # is Reached

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, iteration

I am trying to take a value and have it iterate through each element of a string until it goes through every element, giving me the final value.

below is the code i'm trying with some notes

results from `num = 1.5`, but it changes, just keeping it here for example purposes

```
b = '221212' # this is my string I want each element to represent a value, 
             # for example 2 would equal 2 and 1 would equal .5)

num = num    # that the iteration goes off of. so it would be 1.5 in my case

if int(num) == 2:
    num = 2
elif int(num) != 1.5:
    num = 1.5
    for i in b:
        if i == 2:
            num *= 2
        elif i == 1:
            num += .5
            print('Goal#:', num)
```

what I think I'm telling the code is if integer num == 2 then num is equal to 2, elif the num is not a integer number then the num is equal to 1.5, then I'm what I'm trying to tell the code is to take the number 1.5 and iterate through until it reaches a specific number, in this case 27. below is the exact results I'm expecting but the output isn't giving me what I need:

```
 b = 221212
(2)21212: 1.5 * 2 = 3
2(2)1212: 3 * 2 = 6 
22(1)212: 6 + .5 = 6.5
221(2)12: 6.5 * 2 = 13
2212(1)2: 13 + .5 = 13.5
22121(2): 13.5 * 2 = 27
Goal is 27
```

I want `b` to be read as a list like `b = [2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]` and for each element I want the `num` (1.5) to be either multiplied by 2 if the element in b is 2 or have .5 added if the element in b is 1 until it gets to the end of the list.

Comment: thanks for the edit I was thinking of cleaner ways to do this

Comment: Your code does not work - you have plain text w/o marking it as comment in it. You use `num` as variable and as variable of your loop - why? thats confusing. You are calculating something, but you use * and + for things - why and how?  Why `elif int(num) != 1.5:` -that is always true, you cannot have any integer thats equal to 1.5 - etc. Please clarify your code, input, goal, output and where your problem is. See [ask] and [mre]. Thanks

Comment: I guess I can explain it like this: I want b to be read as a list like b = [2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2] and for each element I want the num(1.5) to be either multiplied by 2 if the element in b is 2 or have .5 added if the element in b is 1 until it gets to the end of the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `num` as variable and as variable of your loop - why? That is confusing.

> ```
> elif int(num) != 1.5:
> ```

is always true (hence obsolete) because any integer is always unequal to `1.5`.

> ```
> for i in b:
>     if i == 2:
>         num *= 2
>     elif i == 1:
>         # etc.
> ```

does nothing. `b` is a string - hence `i` are strings (of lenght 1). They are *never* equal to either 1 or 2 (both integers).

---

You want the elements of `b` as indicator what to do and do stuff to `num`. You do not need to "integerize" the characters in b - simply compare against the character and apply whatever rule you want if that character occures:

```
b = '221212'
num = 1.5

for c in b:
    print(f"{num} given '{c}' leads to ", end="")
    if c == "2":            # is it a '2' string: multiply with 2
        num = num * 2
    elif c == "1":          # is it a '1' string: add 0.5
        num += 0.5
    print(num)
```

Output:

```
1.5 given '2' leads to 3.0
3.0 given '2' leads to 6.0
6.0 given '1' leads to 6.5
6.5 given '2' leads to 13.0
13.0 given '1' leads to 13.5
13.5 given '2' leads to 27.0
```

---

If you need a 1-liner (excluding the import), you can leverage lambdas and [reduce](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/functools.html#functools.reduce):

```
from functools import reduce

print(reduce( lambda x,w: x*2 if w=="2" else x+0.5, "221212", 1.5))
```

which only works for `'2'` and `'1'` in your string - any non `'2'` will be interpreted as `'1'` - adding 0.5 to your result.

Comment: Sorry for the confusing code. I'm really new to python and I was trying to reverse a loop equation I saw in a reddit post. Thank you for the help Patrick!